# Cache IP from GeoPlugin PHP result

Tags: php

I am using GeoPlugin to test for what country visitors are browsing from, and redirecting them based on the result. At the moment I have the code on every page, so every page is making the same request. Is it possible to do the lookup once per IP address and cache the result for a while, to reduce the number of requests to GeoPlugin. My code so far is:

```
<?php 

$meta = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

if (($meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='CN' || 
     $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='IR'
    )&&(        
     $meta['geoplugin_request']!=='1.2.3.4'
   ))       
{
    header('Location: http://google.com', true);
    die();
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Store it somewhere and do the lookup there first.

Comment: $_SESSION could save your day, make the lookup once, each page check if present, if not do the lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final code is as follows, using a session as suggested above:

```
<?php

session_start();

if( isset( $_SESSION['geoplugin'] ) )

{
  $meta=$_SESSION['geoplugin'];
    echo "Using a stored session";
}

else

{
   $meta = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

   $_SESSION['geoplugin'] = $meta;

    echo "Using a new session";
}

if (
(
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='CN' || 
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='HK' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='TW' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='AP' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='ID' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='KP' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='KR' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='MN' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='MY' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='PG' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='PH' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='VN' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='IN' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='BD' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='RK' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='RU' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='PL' ||
    $meta['geoplugin_countryCode']=='BG'
)

&&
(       
    $meta['geoplugin_request']!=='1.2.3.4'
)
)

{

header('Location: https://mywebsite.co.uk/denied', true);
}

$status = session_status();

if($status == PHP_SESSION_DISABLED)
{
echo "Session is Disabled";
}
else if($status == PHP_SESSION_NONE )
{
 echo "Session Enabled but No Session values Created";
}
else
{
echo "Session Enabled and Session values Created";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the session storage idea, but here is a more persistent cache which is also useful for bots etc which don't store session data, and which use IP address pools.

```
<?php

    // Check if IP country already known - assume a class C is all in 1 country
    $cachedir="/tmp/countries";

    preg_match('/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.\d{1,3}/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $a);
    $ipfile=$cachedir."/".$a[1].".".$a[2].".".$a[3];

    if (file_exists($ipfile)) {
            // We have already met an IP from this Class C, so get the cached value
            $cc=file_get_contents($ipfile);
    } else {
            $ipdata = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
            $cc=$ipdata->geoplugin_countryCode;

            // Now we have the country code, save it for next time
            if (!file_exists($cachedir)) {
                    mkdir($cachedir, 0777);
            }
            file_put_contents($ipfile, $cc);
    }

    // Now we can decide what to do, based on the CC
    if (! preg_match('/AU|NZ|PH|US|CA|UK/', $cc) ){
            print "Not today, Sunshine!";
            exit;
    }

    print "Welcome";
```